# Training a binary operator

Tags: tensorflow

I'm learning about neural networks and machine learning in general and wanted to perform a simple binary operator implementation in Tensorflow. I know implementing an operator is simple and is not a usual task for a neural network, but I want to know if I can set up a neural network and let it learn the operator for itself.

The main goal is to use two input nodes and one output node and train an AND operator. The problem is there are only four samples altogether:

```
0 && 0 == 0
0 && 1 == 0
1 && 0 == 0
1 && 1 == 1
```

When I train my network with this I always get extremely poor examples (probably because of underfitting?)

Now is this even doable? Should I even approach it this way? I can update the question with my code if it is relevant. Thanks for any insights!